# how ejs converting to excel

Tags: node.js, ejs, xlsx, exceljs

- I am currently working on a Node.js project. I need a functionality that allows the code I wrote in HTML to be created in an Excel sheet. If there is any such package or library, please let me know.
- html convert excel, EJS convert html -- html convert excel, and css work in excel.
  I hope to get a response to this soon